# How do you run script like tasks in Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I realize there may be multiple ways to do this and I would like to know what the tradeoffs are for all of them.

I have a group of nodes being set up by a docker Compose. They all must use the same PostGRESQL database (which is a container outside of them, connected with an external link).

I would like to run a startup script to create the databases and tables for these. One of the nodes is for node.js which makes it difficult to install PSQL (because it doesn't inherit from an OS image).

I would like to avoid the owners of the group of nodes connecting to the server. Ideally they should dump an SQL file in their repository and this should automatically create the Database and tables for them.

Any ideas/Best practices on how to run one time scripts when building the containers?

Here's my docker-compose

```
   version: '2'

   services:
     web:
       build: 'main_server'
       ports: 
         - 3000
       external_links:
         - some-postgres:postgres
       network_mode: bridge
     backend:
       build: 'data_controller'
       network_mode: bridge
```

This is the PostGRESQL file I want to import:

```
CREATE USER docker;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE bzucker3_db TO docker;
CREATE TABLE location (
    id                  varchar(12),
    location            varchar(50),
    name                varchar(30)     PRIMARY KEY,
    building_name       varchar(90),
    building_id         varchar(30),
    floor               varchar(1),
    room                varchar(30)
);

CREATE TABLE count (
    clientCount         int,
    clientCount_2_4GHz  int,
    clientCount_5GHz    int,
    name                varchar(30)     PRIMARY KEY,
);
```

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/ describes how to map sql files into the container so they are loaded automatically on startup. Please check the "How to extend this image" section...

Comment: @nwinkler  looked at that. The issue with that is I don't want to extend the image. I said this is an EXTERNAL postgresql link. Since it's external it's not being built with the other images, which makes extending the PostGres not possible

Comment: Right, I missed that, sorry.

Comment: One thing I do in similar situations is to add a client lib to the container that runs scripts that are placed in a defined location. For Node.js, I would build something using https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres, for Java, I use [Jisql](https://bitbucket.org/stdunbar/jisql). These usually don't require the PSQL libs, so you don't have to deal with installing. Not a one-size-fits-all, but it should work in your case...

Comment: Yeah. That was how I was thinking of going about it. That works for right now, but that way I'm putting the onus of figuring out how to run the script on the programmer. Not sure that I want to do that. :-(

Comment: Define a directory for each of the containers and have the script/program pick up files from that directory - similar to how the Postgres image does